# GPT2 huggingface's transformer preprocessing

Tags: huggingface-transformers

What should we do exactly during the preprocessing step for GPT2? Are there any guidelines?

Would this be just fine for the preprocessing step?

```
1. Remove any \n from sentence
2. Remove extra spaces from sentence
3. Leave everything else that is part of the sentence but not exactly words (e.g. urls, non-english words that may be added in an english sentence, emojis, etc...)
```

Wouldn't it be better to remove extra punctuation or any non-english character?

Comment: Please clarify your question, and update it including a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: @dennlinger I just added a pseudo-code snippet for what I'm thinking it could work for the preprocessing step